# Is there a debugging tool for rabbitmq queue tracing?

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there a debugging tool for rabbitmq queue tracing? Once there is a problem with the queue, it is possible to locate the problem

Comment: What kind of the problem?

Comment: Is there a tool to track rabbitmq's queues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html

> When the feature is turned off, it has no effect on performance; when it is turned on, performance will drop somewhat due to additional messages being generated and routed.